# Why was the question about Pixelated Art closed as Too Broad?

Tags: discussion

Regarding: [Pixelized works of art](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108497/pixelized-works-of-art)

Is it a wording of the Close Reasons that is creating issues?

A moderator went as far as commenting:

> I don't think this question is a good fit for the SE model. There is no 'right' answer, and 'recognizable' is a **very subjective quality**.

Another user followed that up with:

> The Graphic Design Q&A model requires objective questions with objective answers. Check the help center on how to ask a good question.

So, why are you all voting to close as Too Broad instead of Primarily Opinion Based?

Comment: This wouldn't be the first time (in recent events) that the wording of a close reason came up. (see [this](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3417/63979))

Comment: @WELZ it shows you voted on it, did you vote as broad or something else?

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I voted as too broad, I don't believe that all the names there voted the same though (I'm pretty sure it goes by majority)

Comment: The question is now gone but I remember when I read it that I had this feeling where I could really envision someone asking this in a lazy way, to create a popular blog post with cool pixelized art out of this community's answers.

Answer (score 4):

When I look at this question I can see why it's too broad regarding the spectrum of images that are black and white pixelated with representation of famous works of art.  There really is no logic in a primarily opinion based because what opinion is there for finding other images that are:

> I'm looking for other examples of famous works of art which can be
>   recognized by a minimal number of black and white pixels.

My second argument would be this should have been closed for resource gathering with a custom reason such as this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/108504/wacom-tablet-variants).

Comment: Why is it regularly considered *resource gathering* (and being lazy) when a single person's resources just don't suffice for searching "the whole internet" - but if a "colleague" were out there who could help? (I don't want anyone to do my _work_ (of searching) - but if someone already has found what I am looking for?)

Comment: Another comment: There are probably not _so_ many "images that are black and white pixelated with representation of famous works of art", at least not when you set the upper pixel dimensions to - say - 20x20. Should I reformulate my question accordingly: "Which representations of famous works of art with less than 20x20 pixels are there?"

Comment: I think you're missing the issue in hand. Your question doesn't fit within the SE model and it's been noted in a comment. The assumption that you're lazy might be based on the level the question falls.  You establish no data where you've tried to help yourself and if you have, then that is why the common comment of `Show us what you've tried` exists.  We are not mind readers nor are we to assume what your intent is here accept for others to find. As stated and as something I still firmly believe your question is not something I think is going to really benefit anyone that comes to the site.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, because I strongly believe that my question **is** something that may benefit anyone (or at least *someone*) who comes to the site. (But obviously I failed to make this clear - my fault.)

Comment: BTW: What I have tried: lots of Google searches like "pixel-art famous". Adding something like  "work of art", "minimal", "20x20" didn't help. Any recommendations?

Comment: Also, this may not be a question suited for the site but that doesn't mean a question of this nature would be off topic for the chatroom.  That **could** be an option as well.  Keep in mind, it's always better to list what you've tried in the body of the question, leaving it as a comment when a cluster of comments exist will be overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

Too broad because the user was asking others to search for them. The question wasn't asking for anything more, including opinions.

Note, my vote was cast **before** the edit to the question which added the opinion-based "how to" factor.

er... or was I thinking of his other question?? Not seeing my vote there after looking again. eh.. maybe I thought it but didn't vote.... I'm gettin' old.